# C error cannot convert argument 1 from int * to int

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, int

new to C and learning. I keep getting error (C2664: 'int readScores(int,int,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to 'int'). I have no clue on how to fix it. I'v tried looking it up but don't understand the error code...
How can I fix it?
Also any pointers and or/tips on the code would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

// Functions 
int readScores(int test1, int test2, int test3);
int determineGrade(int test1, int test2, int test3);
void print(int test1, int test2, int test3);


int main(void)
{
    int test1;
    int test2;
    int test3;
    readScores(&test1, &test2, &test3);
    determineGrade(test1, test2, test3);
    print(test1, test2, test3);
    return 0;
}

void readScores(int *test1, int *test2, int *test3)
{
    // Promts
    printf("Hello, this program will determine");
    printf("the grades of average test scores");
    printf("to see if you passed or not this year.");
    printf("Please enter in the three test...");
    printf("Note: only enter scores that are (0-100)");

    printf("Enter in test1\n");
    scanf("%d", test1);
    printf("Enter in test2\n");
    scanf("%d", test2);
    printf("Enter in test 3\n");
    scanf("%d", test3);
    return;
}
int determineGrade(int test1, int test2, int test3)
{
    // Local declrations
    int average;

    // Math
    average = 3 / (test1 + test2 + test3);
    return average;
}
void print(int test1, int test2, int test3)
{
    int Grade;
    Grade = determineGrade(test1, test2, test3);
    if (Grade > 90)
    {
        printf("Great job you have an A %d int the class\n", Grade);
        return;
    }
    else if (70 < Grade > 90, test3)
    {
        if (test3 < 90)
        {
            printf("Good job you got a A %d\n", Grade);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Easy Beezy you got a B %d for the class\n", Grade);
            return;
        }
        return;
    }
    else if (50 < Grade > 70, test2, test3)
    {
        Grade = 2 / (test2 + test3);
        if (Grade > 70)
        {
            printf("You passed congrats you have a C %d for the class\n", Grade);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You have a D for the class %d\n", Grade);
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (Grade < 50)
    {
        printf("Yeah you might want to take this class again you have a F %d\n", Grade);
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your declaration for `readScores` does not match your definition for `readScores`. Parameter types are different. Even the return types are different. This makes no sense. What were you trying to do by making a mismatched definition? Are you the author of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int readScores(int test1, int test2, int test3);` method is declared with int type but you define(and call) it with pointers.

Change declaration to be `int readScores(int* test1, int* test2, int* test3);`

Comment: Changing the scanf call is wrong -- it expects an address, not an int.

Answer (score 2):

You must make the function prototype, e.g.

```
int readScores(int test1, int test2, int test3);
```

match the actual function implementation:

```
void readScores(int *test1, int *test2, int *test3)
```

---

To elaborate a bit. The data flow in your program is good, you declare three variables in main, pass pointers to those as arguments to `readScores` which then will modify them. The variables are then used for printing and calculation. So your only problem is that you first incorrectly tell the compiler "readScores has three int arguments" while you implement it with three int pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, there is no need to call

```
determineGrade(test1, test2, test3);
```

as you called and really used it in your print function. Also, the `determineGrade` function seems a little off. For the average, you want the sum of the grades to be in the numerator and the 3 to be in the denominator:

```
average = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
```

Although not necessary when taking the average of grades from 0-100, when taking averages in the future, it would be good to take each part of the numerator and divide them separately by the denominator and then add them:

```
average = (test1 / 3) + (test2 / 3) + (test3 / 3);
```

This avoids an overflow if your denominator terms may sum to greater than `MAX_INT`.